# Python: SOAP request with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, xml, soap, suds

Python 2.7, Suds.

I'm pulling data from a SOAP API. We have been sending our arguments as a dict, although they can be sent as XML.

Recently, we switched to using a new function in their API which calls for multiple arguments with the same element name. An example request in XML would look like:

```
<Name>
    <Item>John</Item>
    <Item>Sally</Item>
</Name>
```

This would obviously result in duplicate keys if you just tried to convert it to a dict.

Our (non-programmer) support rep recommended "putting each name on a separate line." I suppose that would mean `{'Name': {'Item': 'John\nSally'}}` but that looks wrong and he has a history of being wrong.

I know technically only a programmer from the API team could probably give the correct answer but I can't seem to get in touch with anyone like that. To complicate matters, the request is for a search, so I have no way of knowing if the arguments were passed correctly based on the response in and of itself.

Essentially I'm just asking if anyone can offer some guesses of things they might try, or if anyone has encountered something like this before. And yes, I'm aware that I could switch to sending my requests as XML, but would prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
{'Name': {'Item': ['John', 'Sally']}}
```

Here we explicitly pass a list with items since the meaning of multiple items is basically equal-rank objects in that list.